# rsync denied to access directory when run with launchctl

Tags: launchd, smb, rsync, sandbox

I have mounted samba share in "/Volumes/Samba"  with full read/write access right to it.

I created simple script to rsync files from smb share to folder on my disk, when I lunch script from terminal it works without a problem
but when I create cron or launchctl to run job periodically  I'm getting:

> rsync: opendir "/Volumes/Samba/." failed: Operation not permitted (1)  in rsync log and system log are

In console I see:

> Sandbox: rsync(68990) System Policy: deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Samba
>   Violation:       System Policy: deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Samba

I tried to change access rights or add rsync/script to FDA but nothing helped.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.